# Submit iTunes podcast programmatically

Tags: itunes

Did anyone submit iTunes podcast RSS via code? Or http://podcastsconnect.apple.com/ is the only way to submit podcast?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to [their doco](https://help.apple.com/itc/podcasts_connect/#/itcd88ea40b9), it appears that manual submission is the only way at present.

You could try to reaching out to Apple directly via [the iTunes partner contact form](https://itunespartner.apple.com/contact?content_type=podcasts) and asking them if they have an api available to use?

Also, it might be worth posting this question on the [Apple 'Producing Podcasts' community forum](https://discussions.apple.com/community/professional_applications/producing_podcasts).

Sorry I couldn't find the actual answer you were looking for. Hope that helps you continue moving in the right direction.